# Can't access user control Public Methods in SharePoint application page

Tags: application-pages, user-controls

I have an user control say test.ascx. I have added this to my SharePoint project under control templates section. I registered this user control in my application page.
The Problem is I cant access public methods of user control and they are not listed in intellisense. Even if I am adding also I am getting errors.
I copied my user control in 14/ControlTemplates folder but no use. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by User Control? You copied just acsx file? What about the DLL that takes the code behind? Did you debug the code?

Comment: yes i debuged the code.i can see ascx file controls are rendered on runtime on browser.Only issue is i cant access the public methods in that file. i created acsx file in same project so same dll.